# WinDbg, How to display version control file path in stack trace with source server?

Tags: version-control, windbg, stack-trace

I am using WinDbg with the source server so that it will display the source information in stack traces.  But it shows the path where the source was built, not where it exists in my version control system.

Is there a way to have it display the paths from my version control system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way that I have found to do this is to extract the source control information from the relevant .pdb's used (using pdbstr) and use that information to replace the build paths with the version control paths.

Too bad WinDbg doesn't have an easy way to do this given that it has the info already.

Answer (score 0):

The paths in the stack trace will reflect the file location at compile time.

Comment: I know that.  But I am storing the version control information in the .pdb's as well.  WinDbg uses this info to automagically download the source file if I click on a stack frame.  I want to know how to display the version control path.